# Azure Kubernetes keep-alive TCP socket

Tags: azure, nginx, kubernetes, timeout, kubernetes-ingress

I want to connect a mobile device that opens a TCP connection to one of my kubernetes services. The problem is that the connection is killed before the heartbeat interval of 10 minutes.

Below is my deployment

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: device-gateway
  labels:
    app: device-gateway
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 0
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: device-gateway
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: device-gateway
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: device-gateway
        image: [IMAGE]
        imagePullPolicy: Always
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: myregistrykey
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: device-gateway
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - name: my-device-port
    port: 8485
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: device-gateway
```

I have tried setting the following annotations in my Ingress

```yaml
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-socket-keepalive: "on"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "1800s"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-stream-timeout: "1800s"
nginx.org/proxy-send-timeout: "1800s"

service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-tcp-idle-timeout: "30"
```

Also, the "idle timeout" in the public IP is set to 30 minutes. Same goes for the LoadBalancer rule.

I installed the ingress controller like this:

```sh
helm install nginx-ingress ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx \
    --set tcp.8485="default/device-gateway:8485" \
    --set [more irrelevant settings here]
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with configuration, so how do I get the timeout to be 30 minutes?

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up the cluster? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud providor? It is important to reproduce your problem.

Comment: I used Azure as cloud provider. The version I will find out in a minute

Comment: I did not find the solution to the problem, but I did remove the problem by send a heartbeat the other way every 5 minutes to keep the line open.

Comment: Did you try to set idle timeout like [in this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-tcp-idle-timeout?tabs=tcp-reset-idle-portal)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have posted community wiki answer to summarize the topic.

OP has found a workaround. He has mentioned about it in the comment:

> I did not find the solution to the problem, but I did remove the problem by send a heartbeat the other way every 5 minutes to keep the line open.

I have found article about [Configure TCP reset and idle timeout for Azure Load Balancer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-tcp-idle-timeout?tabs=tcp-reset-idle-portal). It could help [set tcp reset and idle timeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-tcp-idle-timeout?tabs=tcp-reset-idle-portal#set-tcp-reset-and-idle-timeout) from the [Azure portal](https://portal.azure.com/).

Comment: Thank you for posting an answer. I have already set the timeouts mentioned in the article though. I will keep trying to fix the timeouts and I will post the answer when I find it.

Comment: Some time has passed, but no updates from my side. I tried to configure the Load Balancing Rule for the concerning port to have a 30 minute timeout, but the device reconnects after 10 minutes nevertheless (which is its trigger to send a heartbeat). Other devices with a heartbeat of 5 minutes, keep their connection as expected.